# Error in multiple linear regression in r studio

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm having an issue with running a multiple linear regression in r. Essentially I am trying to model tree height by a tree's crown width and dividing the data into evergreen trees and deciduous trees. (functional_type2).  When I get the regression table to get the values for the linear model it give an estimate for evergreen trees but not deciduous trees.

This is the code I am using from (moderndive)

```r
trees_mlr <- lm(Tree_Height ~ Crown_Width + Functional_Type2, near_reed_top_4)
trees_mlr
get_regression_table(trees_mlr)

Numeric Variables :(Crown_Width) (Tree_Height)
Categorical Variable: (Functional_Type2)
```

Output:

[image: MLR Output]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547577/multiple-regression-r-output-how-to-interpret-the-intercept/547588#547588

Answer (score 1):

You have only two types in the category `functional_type2`. The other coefficients you can see in your table (namely, intercept and Crown_Width) belong to deciduous_trees (as the default type of tree). If you need the forecast for the `Evergreen`, you add its coefficient 62.456 on top of the other two.

Comment: I may have phrased the question poorly but I also need the estimate for Deciduous.  I am looking for the table to have a row Functional_Type2: Deciduous.  I am not sure why I am not getting that as Functional Type has two categories within it.

Comment: You can add it with the coefficient 0.0 and p = 1.0 :-)